# Relative position between \draw and axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, axis

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        axis x line = center,
        axis y line = center,
        xmin        = -3.0,
        xmax        =  5.0,
        ymin        = -3.0,
        ymax        =  5.0]
        \addplot[
            domain = 0.1:5.0,
        ] {1/x};
    \end{axis}
    
    \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(4,4)/x_0, (3,1)/B, (1,4)/P_1, (3,4)/P_1}
    \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The code above will generate the following graph:

[image]

I was trying to add the text `x0` around the point (1,1) in the `axis` environment. But it seems that the coordinate system between the `axis` environment and the `tikzpicture` is different.

Could you help me with explaining the environment misalignment problem?

And how to put the `x0` label at the (1,1) coordinate under the `axis` environment in an elegant way?

Comment: Inside the axis environment one can use `\coordinate (A) at (axis cs: 4,4};` to define a global coordinate, then use `\draw (A) etc `outside the axis environment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Do not use `axis cs:` explicitly - it has been default since long time ago.

Comment: If you really really want to learn about the relationship between coordinates inside and outside the `axis` then there is chapter 4.26 in the manual or see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667195/8650

Comment: @hpekristiansen, I don't trust defaults, especially ones which change.  In C, after int was redefined from short to long, I stopped using int altogether.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: The default for a specific `compat` level does *not* change. I can only say that you should not write it - it is a bad habit that is perpetuated by old posts on this site.

Comment: @hpekristiansen - Clarity is never a bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

The points `P_1`, `P_2`, `B` and x_o˙I would draw wit separate `addplot` function with options `only marks`, `nodes near coords`, and `point meta=explicit symbolic`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = center,
xmin = -3.0,    xmax = 5.0,
ymin = -3.0,    ymax = 5.0,
            ]
%
\addplot [domain = 0.1:5.0, samples=50] {1/x};
\addplot [only marks, mark=*,           % <---
          nodes near coords,            % <--- 
          point meta=explicit symbolic] % <---
          coordinates {(1,1) [$x_0$]    % given coordinate
                       (1,-2)[$B$]      % coordinate estimated from your picture
                       (1,4) [$P_1$]    % <---
                       (-2,4)[$P_1$]};  % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Used coordinates (except for `x_0`) I estimated from your image in question. If needed, correct their positions as you like to have.

Answer (score 1):

The better methode is in answer by @Zarko. You can also just create your points as you are doing, but inside `axis`. The only thing is that you can not use `foreach` in that way. If you need a loop, you need to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and friends - see manual chapter 8.1.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-3.0, xmax=5.0,
ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0,
]
\addplot[domain=0.1:5.0, samples=50, smooth] {1/x};
\fill (1,1) circle[radius=0.05] node[above right] {$x_0$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with curve and a single point]