# How to draw the lateral surface of a truncated cone with tikz 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

This is my first question, I apologize for any inconvenient.
I have two coaxial circumferences that are the basis of a cone. I would like to fill the area between them, as the lateral surface of a cone. How can I do it? Here is what I have.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=1]
     \draw [NavyBlue,line width=.2mm,dashed](0,0) circle (1cm);
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=1.4]
     \draw [NavyBlue,line width=.2mm,dashed](0,0) circle (1.8cm){};
      
   \end{scope}   
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the tangent points and fill the area. You can also use a `surf` plot from PGFPlots like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={radius(\h)=-1+2*\h;}]
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
x=1cm, y=1cm, z={(-3.85mm,-3.85mm)},
anchor=origin, at={(0,0,0)},
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2, zmax=2,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=interp,
samples=50, domain=0:360, variable=a,
samples y=2, domain y=1:1.4, variable y=h,
colormap/violet,
]( {h} , {radius(h)*cos(a)} , {radius(h)*sin(a)} );
\end{axis}
\draw[cyan, thick, dashed, canvas is yz plane at x=1] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw[cyan, thick, dashed, canvas is yz plane at x=1.4] (0,0) circle[radius=1.8];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: truncated violet cone]

I do not know what you need the figure for, so I made the coordinate system match inside and outside the `axis`. If there is no need to align the cone with anything else, then everything could be drawn inside `axis` and no consideration of unit vectors and origin would be needed.

**Edit:** With rotation. Method taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199715/8650

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\newcommand{\ViewAzimuth}{20}
\newcommand{\ViewElevation}{20}
\tikzset{viewport/.style 2 args={
x={({cos(-#1)*1cm},{sin(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
y={({-sin(-#1)*1cm},{cos(-#1)*sin(#2)*1cm})},
z={(0,{cos(#2)*1cm})}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[viewport={\ViewAzimuth}{\ViewElevation}]
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
view={\ViewAzimuth}{\ViewElevation},
every axis plot/.style={very thin},
disabledatascaling,
anchor=origin,
viewport={\ViewAzimuth}{\ViewElevation},
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2, zmax=2,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
shader=interp,
samples=50, domain=0:360, variable=a,
samples y=2, domain y=1:1.4, variable y=h,
colormap/violet,
]( {h} , {(-1+2*\h)*cos(a)} , {(-1+2*\h)*sin(a)} );
\end{axis}
\draw[cyan, thick, dashed, canvas is yz plane at x=1] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw[cyan, thick, dashed, canvas is yz plane at x=1.4] (0,0) circle[radius=1.8];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Truncated cone rotated]
[image: Truncated cone rotated]

Comment: Thank you very much. But if I use this in my tikzpicture I don't see the drawn area matching the circumferences. Is this what you were talking about with unit vector and origin's consideration?

Comment: I use this in your tikzpicture and the circumferences do match. -so you must have changed something!?

Comment: This is what I have:
\tdplotsetmaincoords{20}{20}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={radius(\h)=-1+2*\h;},tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.8,cone back/.style={draw=brown,left color=gray!50,right color=brown},
  cone front/.style={draw=brown,left color=brown}]
     \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=1]
     \draw [NavyBlue,line width=.2mm,dashed](0,0) circle (1cm);
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=1.4]
     \draw [NavyBlue,line width=.2mm,dashed](0,0) circle (1.8cm);
   \end{scope}
\begin{tikzpicture}

Comment: You rotate and you scale your tikzpicture!

Comment: Yeah, I see. If I remove [tdplot_main_coords] it works. But that is a little disappointed, since I would like to draw all the figures and then choose the best view, without having those problems. Is it possible to change the view without changing the picture?

Comment: Very strange and specific starting point, if you anyway want to rotate the result. -see edit.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thank you. However it keeps telling the same error: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate." Do you know why?

Comment: No need to write thank you - just remember to accept the answer. The code as is compiles perfectly. Maybe you again change something? - I can only guess. Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420448/error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-iterate

Comment: Yes, perfect. I was in a beamer, indeed. Thank you again, I'll accept the answer.